# Include UDFs in replication publication on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, functions

When trying to replicate UDFs via snapshot replication on a working database I got an error. So I created a simpler database with only a single UDF to test that I could replicate UDFs, because I've been reading that there might be bugs that depend on how you write the SQL I created a simpler test.

I got the same error with this function, so should I assume that I can't replicate UDFs? I mean, I'm given an option to do exactly this. But even the simplest example fails. Am I doing anything wrong? The error is from the snapshot agent on the publisher's side.

This is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test1 
(
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT 1
    )
END
GO
```

The stacktrace is:

```
Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Target Site: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] ScriptWithList(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyCollection, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject[], Boolean)
Message: Script failed for UserDefinedFunction 'dbo.test1'. 
Stack:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(DependencyCollection depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects, Boolean discoveryRequired)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.EnumScriptWithList(SqlSmoObject[] objects)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(SqlSmoObject[] objects)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.BaseDependencyNode.CreateMirrorCopy(String mirrorCopyName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.BaseDependencyNode.FetchBaseDependenciesWithMirrorCopyTransaction(SqlConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.RetryableSqlServerTransactionManager.ExecuteTransaction(Boolean bLeaveTransactionOpen)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.BaseDependencyNode.FetchBaseDependenciesWithMirrorCopy()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.FunctionDependencyNode.get_BaseDependencies()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.BaseDependencyNode.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.DepthFirstSearchVisit(IDependencyNode dependencyNode)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.DepthFirstSearchVisit(IDependencyNode dependencyNode)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.ArticleDependenciesAnalyzer.PerformArticleDependenciesAnalysis()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.DoReplicationDependenciesAnalysis(Scripter scripter, SqlSmoObject[] smoObjectArray, IDictionary urnKeyArticleLookupTable)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.DoScripting()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.DoScripting()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.GenerateSnapshot()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.SnapshotGenerationAgent.InternalRun()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.Run() (Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Error number: 0)
Get help: http://help/0
```

I'm trying to publish on SQL Server 2012 to a subscriber that is SQL Server 2016. The Distributor is also SQL Server 2016.

I was able to successfully run a snapshot of this UDF on a publication hosted on SQL Server 2016. So I think that it's actually SQL Server 2012 that is not allowing this, assuming that the snapshot agent runs on the publisher.

I've tried with and without the `AS` keyword. The value of `@type` in `sp_addarticle` is 128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was posted on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3083389/transactional-replication-snapshot-agent-error-when-publishing-udfs-to-2012-2014-from-sql-server-2016):

> We can't snapshot any User Defined functions to SQL 2016 version from
>   existing SQL 2014 servers. They work fine within 2016 versions and
>   from SQL 2016 to SQL 2014\2012.

MS's answer is:

> This issue is fixed in the following cumulative update for SQL Server:
>
> Cumulative Update 4 for SQL Server 2016.
>
> It contains one fix: FIX: Snapshot Agent fails when you publish UDF’s
>   to SQL Server 2016 Distributor in Transactional Replication
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3197883/fix-snapshot-agent-fails-when-you-publish-udf-s-to-sql-server-2016-distributor-in-transactional-replication